# SKU, Category, Price & Quantity Not Showing in eCommerce Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to set up eCommerce tracking for donations on a charity website. I've put the code in place and transactions are coming through but I'm missing details like the SKU, Category, Price & Quantity.

Here's a screenshot of GA eCommerce. You can see the data missing.

[image: Here's a screenshot of GA eCommerce.]

And here's the HTML output from the Thank You page.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    var pluginUrl =
      '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
    _gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]); // enhanced link attribution
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount',  'UA-xxxxxxxx-1']); // your GA ID
    _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'xxxx.xx']); // track sub domains
    _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
    _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'xxxx.xx']); // prevent self referrals
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']); // track the page view
    _gaq.push(['_addTrans',
      '525e5cdb1ffd6751ef00000d',           // transaction ID - required
      'xxxx xxxxxx',          // affiliation or store name
      '25',            // total - required
      '', // city
      '', // state or province
      '' // country
    ]);
    _gaq.push(['_addItem',
       '525e5cdb1ffd6751ef00000d', // transaction ID
       'Child sponsorship', // SKU/code – required
       '', // donation type - Ignored
       'Donation', // category or variation
       '25', // unit price – required
       '1' // quantity – required
    ]);
    _gaq.push(['_trackTrans']); // submits transaction to the analytics server
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

Any ideas what could be causing the issue and how it can be solved would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEcommerce?hl=sk#_gat.GA_Tracker_._addItem

> Supply a value for the name parameter at all times.
>   While the name parameter is not required, **items added to a transaction without a name parameter do not appear in the product breakdown for a transaction**. While you will still see the total revenue for the transaction, you will not be able to see how much revenue a particular item contributed to the transaction total.

Since you don't provide item name in `_addItem`, maybe this is the problem. On your screenshot there's Revenue but no products.

Comment: Could it be the same for the category ?

Comment: For category probably not.